# Coroutine keeps going after stopped

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a Street Fighter type game and want you to be able to charge an attack. it it meant to start when you hold the attack key for about 1 second, then it should count up by 0.1 every 0.1 seconds until at a maximum value. after i release the key it should stop where it is and reset the charge. Some reason it starts again after i release the key.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Attack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public KeyCode attackKey;
    public KeyCode stunKey;
    public int damage;
    public bool charging;
    public float maxChargeMultiplier;
    public float charge;
    public float attackDelay;
    public float attackTimer;
    public Stats target;


    private void Start()
    {
        attackTimer = attackDelay;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Start Charge
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(attackKey) && attackTimer >= attackDelay)
        {
            attackTimer = 0;
            StartCoroutine(ChargeAttack());
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(attackKey))
        {
            Damage();
            StopCoroutine(ChargeAttack());
            charge = 0;
            StartCoroutine(RechargeAttack());
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator RechargeAttack()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < attackDelay * 10; i++)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.1f);
            attackTimer += 0.1f;
        }
    }
    public IEnumerator ChargeAttack()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1.25f);

        for(int c = 0; c < maxChargeMultiplier * 10; c++)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.1f);
            charge += 0.1f;
        }
    }

    public void Damage()
    {
        if(target != null)
        {
            if (target.blocking)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                target.health -= Mathf.RoundToInt(damage * charge);
                gameObject.GetComponent<Stats>().combo += 20;
            }
        }

        charge = 0;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.GetComponent<Stats>())
        {
            target = col.gameObject.GetComponent<Stats>();
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.GetComponent<Stats>() == target)
        {
            target = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check its not being started multiple times or by multiple copies of the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the coroutine that was started.

`StartCoroutine` returns a `Coroutine`.  This `Coroutine` is what needs to be stopped.  In order to stop that exact coroutine, we need to store it in a variable so we can reference it again later when we want to stop it.

```
private Coroutine chargeAttackRoutine; // <- Variable for the coroutine that was started

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(attackKey))
    {
        chargeAttackRoutine = StartCoroutine(ChargeAttack()); // <- Store the coroutine
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(attackKey))
    {
        StopCoroutine(chargeAttackRoutine); // <- Stop the coroutine
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very good to know and fixed the problem.